# python package for rar and zip archives

Tags: python, zip, rar

I need to extraxt data from archive in python script.
The first way - use command line with winrar or others programms. This way is platform dependent and i want more universal way.

What packages you can recomend?

python 2.7
archives: rar, zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me Google that for you. zipfile and rarfile:

http://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rarfile/2.2